# How to apply WebTemplateCustomizer conditionally

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My library registers two different `RestTemplate` beans with different names.

Developers using this library can provide their own beans of type `RestTemplateCustomizer`.
Is it possible to apply customizers conditionaly, so `customizerOne` applies to `beanRestTemplateOne` and customizer 2 applies to bean 2?

Is there something for this in spring/boot ouf the box, or would require introducing something like `NamedCustomizer` interface ?

Thanks

Expected to find some mechanism inside spring that can control granularity of customizers.
Right now every custimozer is applied to every bean.